# Is there a way to define generic props when using vue3 with tsx

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, tsx

We have a simple way to define generic vue components when we are in functional mode:

```
type Loading = { status: 'LOADING' }
type Error = { status: 'ERROR'; message: string }
type AsyncData<T> = Loading | { status: 'LOADED'; value: T } | Error

type Props<T> = {
  data: AsyncData<T>
  renderItem: (item: T) => JSX.Element | null
}

const LoadingElement = <T,>(props: Props<T>) => {
  return (
    <div class={`${props.data.status === 'LOADING' ? styles['top-level'] : ''}`} style={props.data.status !== 'LOADED' ? 'display: flex; justify-content: center' : ''}>
      {props.data.status === 'LOADED' ? props.renderItem(props.data.value) : null}
      {props.data.status === 'ERROR' ? (
        <div>
          <HelpTooltip icon="error-warning" text={props.data.message} />
        </div>
      ) : null}
      {props.data.status === 'LOADING' ? <div class={styles.spinner}></div> : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

With this I can use like this:

```
<LoadingElement data={utilisateur.value} renderItem={item => <>{item ? `${item.prenom || '–'} ${item.nom || '–'}` : '–'}</>} />
```

where item is correctly typed.

My main issue is when using defineComponent (ie. when I need to use ref, or watch, or computed,...) I cannot find a way to correctly generify the component.

The least worst we have is to wrap our component inside a functional one.

For example:

```
const GenericComponentHack = <T>() =>
  defineComponent<Props<T>>({ setup(props) => {
    return () => <OtherComponent {...props} />
  })

export const GenericComponent = <T>(props: Props<T>): JSX.Element => {
  const GenericComponentHackInstance = GenericComponentHack<T>()
  // @ts-ignore
  return <GenericComponentHackInstance {...props} />
}
```

This feels quite ugly, is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeap, defineComponent has another signature with a function since 3.3 version.
You can read more about this [here](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#function-signature)

The example from the doc:

```
const Comp = defineComponent(
  <T extends string | number>(props: { msg: T; list: T[] }) => {
    // use Composition API here like in <script setup>
    const count = ref(0)

    return () => {
      // render function or JSX
      return <div>{count.value}</div>
    }
  },
  // manual runtime props declaration is currently still needed.
  {
    props: ['msg', 'list']
  }
)
```

Comment: I removed this as the accepted answer, because the Comp returns all props as `any`... we lose all the typing system with this syntax, I don't even understand why they did this... from their code `defineComponent<Props extends Record<string, any>` the any break everything

Comment: We ended up not puting the props inside the defineComponent, but outside with a @ts-ignore :(